# How to access local directory with script executed in oozie?

Tags: shell, hadoop, copy, oozie

I am running CDH4.5 with virtualbox on my machine. Inside the VM, I have a local directory: `/home/cloudera/logs/abc.log`, and I wanna do a very simple thing, I scheduled a very simple script in oozie to copy the `abc.log` to HDFS (`/user/cloudera/logs/`).

The scheduled job got executed, but in the stderr, it shows me that:
`cannot access /home/cloudera/logs/abc.log: No such file or directory`

Is there anyway that could make this work? Because I wanna schedule a script with oozie to copy files from local to HDFS as a bath job daily. Thanks!!

Answer (score 5):

An Oozie shell action is executed on a random Hadoop node, i.e. not locally on the machine where the Oozie server is running.

To implement an action that is executed locally, you could use the SSH action: http://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.3.2/DG_SshActionExtension.html with localhost. See e.g. https://github.com/airawat/OozieSamples/tree/master/oozieProject/workflowSshAction for a nice complete example.

Alternatively, you can start a shell action and execute a script that will SSH to the correct machine.